# Index Strategy for MySQL Query that matches on one column and between two others

Tags: mysql, index

I have a table that contains a set of measurements for a continuous stream of processes. Although each process is individual, they are categorized into groups. The events have a start and end timestamp and a process group identifier.

The table structure is as follows (InnoDB, MariaDB 10):

**Table Name: measurements**

```
 CREATE TABLE `measurements` (
 `row_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `process_name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `process_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `process_group_id` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
 `measurement_1` float NOT NULL,
 `measurement_2` float NOT NULL,
 `measurement_3` float NOT NULL,
 `measurement_4` float NOT NULL,
 `start_timestamp` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `end_timestamp` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`row_id`),
 KEY `process_group_id` (`process_group_id`,
     `start_timestamp`,`end_timestamp`),
 KEY `process_id` (`process_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB 
  AUTO_INCREMENT=7294932 
  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin
```

I'm designing a query to obtain the sum of measurements 1,2,3 & 4 for all processes running within a group at a particular point in time so that the app can express each measurement for a specific process as a percentage of the total measurements in the group at that time. The start and end times of processes within a group are not synchronized and they are of variable length.

So for a process running in Group 5, at timestamp 1431388800

```
SELECT  SUM(measurement_1), 
        SUM(measurement_2), 
        SUM(measurement_3),
        SUM(measurement_4)
    FROM  measurements
    WHERE  process_group_id = 5
      AND  1431388800 
           BETWEEN start_timestamp 
               AND end_timestamp
```

This query runs, but takes around 0.5s. The table has 8m records and grows by about 30,000 a day.

I have an index on process_group_id, start_timestamp, end_timestamp. However, the query does not appear to use anything but the process_group_id part of the index. I created an additional index on process_group_id alone to check this, and once created EXPLAIN showed it using this index.

After some searching, I saw a suggestion to modify the query and add an ORDER BY clause. Having done this the query is accelerated to around 0.06s and it seems to use the full index. However, I'm unsure as to why:

```
SELECT  process_group_id, 
        SUM(measurement_1), 
        SUM(measurement_2),
        SUM(measurement_3), 
        SUM(measurement_4)
    FROM  measurements
    WHERE  process_group_id = 5
      AND  1431388800 
  BETWEEN start_timestamp 
      AND end_timestamp
    ORDER BY  process_group_id ASC
```

With 30,000 new records a day that requires their shares to be calculated, 0.06s is still not particularly fast. Is there a better way of structuring either the table or designing the query to get a few orders of magnitude quicker, or is a query which matches on one column and then a range query on two others always going to be fairly slow to run?

Comment: Could you provide your table description as SHOW CREATE TABLE measurements\G? It makes things easier for those trying to help you. BTW, welcome to the forum.

Comment: Can the time ranges overlap?  (Ignoring touching at the end-points.)  It makes a big difference to how solvable the problem is.

Comment: Show create table structure added - thanks for the tip @vérace.

Comment: @rick-james measurements can indeed overlap, Event 1 could run from 10:00:01 - 10:30:05, Event 2 could be 09:50:55 - 11:10:30 etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

(Not an answer, but too clumsy for a comment.)

> have an index on process_group_id, start_timestamp, end_timestamp. However the query does not appear to use anything but the process_group_id part of the index.

It is actually using `start_timestamp` although it does not say so.  What was the `key_len`?  That *may* give a clue.  Also try `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...`.

```
AND  1431388800 BETWEEN start_timestamp AND end_timestamp
```

Turn that into the following to see if it helps:

```
AND  start_timestamp <= 1431388800
AND  end_timestamp   >= 1431388800
```

I suspect it is identical, but I am not sure.

Caution.  The difference between `0.5s` and `0.06s` could a warmed up cache.  Run timings twice.  Also, use `SQL_NO_CACHE` to avoid the Query cache.

How wide are the timestamp ranges typically?  How precise is 1431388800?  The values sound like they have a resolution of 1 second.  What if we switched to 1 minute or 1 hour?

After you provide some answers, I will possibly suggest turning this into a Data Warehouse application and discuss Summary tables.

**Edit**

Consider this approach to *storing* the data.  (I still don't have enough details to determine what variant of the following would be optimal.)

Since you have a "processing" phase that leads to the table in question, I suggest rewriting it to store into a different table (either in place of the existing one, or in addition)

```
CREATE TABLE ByMinute (
    process_group_id ...
    ts TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, -- rounded to the minute
    sum_1 FLOAT  -- see below
    sum_2 ...,
    PRIMARY KEY(process_group_id, ts)
);
```

The table contains one row per minute.  That's 0.5M per year, not terribly big.  If converting from the existing structure do `sum_1 += measurement_1` for each row `BETWEEN starttime AND endtime`.

That is possibly more processing than you are currently doing, but it should not be excessive.  And it makes the `SELECT` extremely efficient:

```
SELECT  sum_1, sum_2, sum_3, sum_4
    FROM  ByMinute
    WHERE  process_group_id = 5
      AND  ts = somehow round 1431388800 to a minute
```

You currently have a daily dump.  The processing should be obvious.  If you switch to "streaming" and use the ping-pong method I mentioned, then very similar code can be used for each transient table.  And you would probably have nearly up-to-the-second data all the time.

Comment: I tried using the comparators instead of BETWEEN - no discernible difference in speed. Likewise with the cache, I've disabled it with SQL_NO_CACHE and run different queries with the same structure to avoid that. The resolution could be lowered to minute intervals I guess. Though events in a process group do not start and end at the same points in time, using minute resolution wouldn't necessarily harm the calculations. For a test query: key_len = 4, rows = 855212. There's no explain format=json in MariaDB 10 I'm afraid.

Comment: I have two thoughts on how to optimize this, but first another question:  When, relative to `start_timestamp` and `end_timestamp`, do you `INSERT` the row with the measurements?

Comment: Measurements for the previous 24 hours are stored into JSON files and delivered to a central store once the day rolls over into the next. The files are then processed in a batch - the read and insert takes a few minutes, the calculation currently takes about ~35 minutes. It's not the end of the world, but does mean that if the data supply becomes streaming/realtime at any point in the future, these calculations can't be done on the fly.

Comment: Yes, you can do the calculations "on the fly".  However, it is a bit more complicated.  I would suggest storing the "raw" data in a transient table, then processing them.  This can be especially efficient by ping-ponging a pair of tables as discussed in [my ingestion blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table).